# Drawer fragment's container is null so I can't inflate it

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation-drawer

I have the following:

activity_main.xml: contains framelayout and a fragment to hold the drawer which is more than just a listview

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <FrameLayout android:id="@+id/container" android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <fragment android:id="@+id/navigation_drawer"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/navigation_drawer_width" android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:name="com.example.example.drawer.DrawerFragment"
        tools:layout="@layout/drawer_fragment" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

drawer_fragment.xml with an image on top of a listview

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:paddingRight="16dp"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/profilePhoto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:contentDescription="@null"
        android:layout_height="128dp" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/lvOptions"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="3dp"
        android:background="#cccc"
        tools:context=".NavigationDrawerFragment" />

</LinearLayout>
```

When `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);` of MainActivity is executed, it also executes onCreateView of the drawer fragment automatically but the container is null. I do the following:

```
View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.drawer_fragment, container, false);
mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
```

but mDrawerLayout is null after that, I guess it's because the container is null, so what am I missing?

Comment: A drawer layout (inflated in activity) contains a content frame and a drawer (the fragment). So in the fragment you're not looking for drawer layout, you're looking for the list view. Yeah, it's confusing at first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The layout `R.layout.drawer_fragment` doesn't contain a view with id `R.id.drawer_layout`, so yes, `mDrawerLayout` will always be null. If you want access to the view with id `drawer_layout`, you'll need to to be calling from the Activity.